# Almost sure convergence of $ \frac{ X_n +1}{n } $

Tags: self-study, inference, convergence

Given that $P( \ X_n = n^2 -1 ) = n^{-2} , n \ge 1  $

$P( \ X_n = -1 ) = 1- \frac{1}{n^2}    $

$ Show $

$ \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{ X_n +1}{n }    $  converges almost sure and

$ \  S_n = X_1+...X_n , $

$show  $

$ \frac{\ S_n }{n} \rightarrow -1 $

**My attempt**

For $P( \ X_n = n^2 -1 ) = n^{-2} $

$ \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{ X_n +1}{n } = \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{ 1+ n^2}{n^3 }  $

$ \sum_{n =1}^\infty [ \frac{ 1}{n^3 } + \frac{1}{n} ]  $

Which $ \rightarrow 1 $  as $ n \rightarrow   \infty $

For $P( \ X_n = -1 ) = 1- \frac{1}{n^2} $

$ \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{ X_n +1}{n } = \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{ -1 }{n^3 }  $

Which $ \rightarrow -1 $  as $ n \rightarrow   \infty $

***Can anyone please tell if I am going the right way ??
Please let me know how to proceed  for $ \ S_n $ part , I tried but I am not getting it -1***

Comment: Why do you say $\sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{ X_n +1}{n } = \sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{ 1+ n^2}{n^3 }$ ?

Comment: @henry ,  I forgot to add $ \ n ^{-2} $ minus sign here  $  \frac{\frac{1}{n^2} +1 }{n } = \frac{1+n^2}{n^3} $

Comment: I suspect the key point is that $X_n \not =-1$ for finitely many $n$ with probability $1$

Comment: @henry could you please  elaborate  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should specify that the random variables $X_n$ are independent, otherwise this problem isn't well-defined.

To make the problem easier, note that we can rewrite $Y_n = X_n+1$ so that the problem becomes

> Given random independent variables $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, $ where $Y_n\sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/n^2)\cdot n^2$, show that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{Y_i}{i}$ converges almost surely as $n\to\infty$ and that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\to 0$.

The first half is true by Borel-Cantelli since that tells us that almost surely, only a finite number of the terms are nonzero. The second one follows by the same reasoning. Almost surely, only a finite number of terms are nonzero, so since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty Y_i$ is almost-surely finite, we must have $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\to 0$.

Comment: hey  , , is there a way to solve this question without using borel cantelli lemma ?

Comment: I doubt it. There aren't very many tools for showing almost sure convergence, and this happens to be one of the most commonly used ones.